# Fatal error: Call to undefined method ShopProductWriter::getProducer()

Tags: php, object, methods, undefined, call

I'm faced with a problem:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method ShopProductWriter::getProducer() in C:\OSPanel\domains\zandstra.com\index.php on line 37

What could have caused it?

```
<?php

class ShopProduct {
    public $title;
    public $producerSurName;
    public $producerFirstName;
    public $price = 0;

    public function __construct (
        $title,
        $firstName,
        $surName,
        $price
    )

    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->producerFirstName = $firstName;
        $this->producerSurName = $surName;
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    public function getProducer () {
        return $this->producerFirstName . " " . $this->producerSurName;
    }
}
$product1 = new ShopProduct (
    "My Antonia",
    "Willa",
    "Cather",
    "5.99"
);


class ShopProductWriter {
    public function write ($shopProduct){
        $str=$shopProduct->title . ":" . $shopProduct->getProducer()
            . " (".$shopProduct->price.")\n";
        print $str;
    }
}
$product1 = new ShopProductWriter("My Antonia", "Willa", "Cather", 5.99);
$writer = new ShopProductWriter();
$writer->write($product1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
$product1 = new ShopProductWriter("My Antonia", "Willa", "Cather", 5.99);
```

you re-created `$product1`, which was until then a `ShopProduct`. From that, `$product1` is a `ShopProductWriter` object. This has no `getProducer()` method, it has only a `write()` method. It is a typo in your code, I think you have re-written your code multiple times and some old initializations left wht you should have get out. In this form, probably does what you want:

```
<?php

class ShopProduct {
    public $title;
    public $producerSurName;
    public $producerFirstName;
    public $price = 0;

    public function __construct (
        $title,
        $firstName,
        $surName,
        $price
    )

    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->producerFirstName = $firstName;
        $this->producerSurName = $surName;
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    public function getProducer () {
        return $this->producerFirstName . " " . $this->producerSurName;
    }
}

class ShopProductWriter {
    public function write ($shopProduct){
        $str=$shopProduct->title . ":" . $shopProduct->getProducer()
            . " (".$shopProduct->price.")\n";
        print $str;
    }
}
$product1 = new ShopProduct("My Antonia", "Willa", "Cather", 5.99);
$writer = new ShopProductWriter();
$writer->write($product1);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you !